# JavaScript: Enum Flag check

Tags: javascript, enums

I want to check if a flag is set in my enum value. 
What is wrong with my code?

Javascript-Code

```
var flags = {
  FOO: 1,
  BAR: 2,
  BAZ: 4,
  FUM: 8,
  ERROR: 65
}

var value = flags.FOO | flags.BAR;

if (value & flags.ERROR){
   alert("ERROR IS SET, but this is not true");
}
```

Comment: 65? 65 is 1+64. IF you want bitmask values, then `ERROR` must be `64`.

Comment: What exactly does now work as expected? `value & flats.ERROR` share the `FOO` bit (2^0) which means the condition is true.

Answer (score 3):

First yours values should be n^2:

```
var flags = {
  UNKNOWN: 0, 
  FOO: 1,
  BAR: 2,
  BAZ: 4,
  FUM: 8,
  ERROR: 16
}
```

Then your statement should be:

```
if ((value & flags.ERROR) == flags.ERROR){
   alert("ERROR IS SET");
}
```